# I need a time to be changed by what the user inputs using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

So on the excel sheet1 I have a list of information I need from the user.(there is a picture of it) On there we have starting time and execution time. This information is passed to sheet3 and I want the ending time to be change depending on the execution time. For example if the user inputs starting time= 1:00 pm and the excution time = 30 minutes. I would want the code to put at the endtime on sheet 3 = 1:30 pm. Here is the current code I have: [image]

```
Sub findData()
    Dim workflow As String
    Dim finalrow As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        workflow = .Range("C5").Value
        servergri = .Range("C9").Value
        gridf = .Range("C9").Value
        StartTime = .Range("c11").Value
    End With

    With Sheets("Sheet3")
        finalrow = .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 5 To finalrow
            If .Cells(i, 3) = workflow And (.Cells(i, 4) = servergri Or .Cells(i, 5) = gridf) Then

                .Rows(i).Insert
                'Add new information to the new row.
                'The new row number is still = i

                .Cells(i, 3) = workflow
                .Cells(i, 4) = servergri
                .Cells(i, 6) = StartTime
                    .Cells(i, 3).Resize(2, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 8


                'If you only want to add one row then your should exit the loop
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it, but you need to make sure the user only enters the time in minutes. EG "60" for 1 hour or "15" for 15 minutes. They should not enter a label.

```
Sub findData()
Dim workflow As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim StartTime as Date
Dim ExecutionTime as Long

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    workflow = .Range("C5").Value
    servergri = .Range("C9").Value
    gridf = .Range("C9").Value
    On Error Goto Next
    StartTime = .Range("c11").Value
    If Err Then
        MsgBox "You didn't enter a valid start time.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ExecutionTime = .Range("c16").Value
    If Err Then
        MsgBox "You didn't enter a valid execution time.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error Goto 0
End With

With Sheets("Sheet3")
    finalrow = .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 5 To finalrow
        If .Cells(i, 3) = workflow And (.Cells(i, 4) = servergri Or .Cells(i, 5) = gridf) Then
            .Rows(i).Insert
            'Add new information to the new row.
            'The new row number is still = i

            .Cells(i, 3) = workflow
            .Cells(i, 4) = servergri
            .Cells(i, 6) = StartTime
                .Cells(i, 3).Resize(2, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 8

            'You don't mention where this time should go on Sheet 3, so I used Cell(i, 9)
            'TimeSerial(Hours, Minutes, Seconds)
            .Cells(I, 9).Value = StartTime + TimeSerial(0, ExecutionTime, 0) 
            .Cells(I, 9).NumberFormat = "hh:mm"

            'If you only want to add one row then your should exit the loop
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End With
End Sub
```